# Solution space for exponential function

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, exponential-function

Let $f$ be a function of $x$ with parameters $0<a<1$ and $0<b<0.5$ as follows:

$$
f(x) = 2 (1+a)^x - 2^x (a^{bx} + a^{(1-b)x})
$$

We are looking for parameters $(a,b)$ such  that there will be a solution $f(x)=0$ for $x>0$. The conjecture is:
We have solutions $f(x) = 0 $ for all $a$ and for $b < b_0$ where $b_0$ is given by $b_0 = (\log(1+a) -\log( 2))/(\log(a))   $.

The questions looks for a formal proof.

Here is an informal approach:

On  the borders of the intervals for $a$ and $b$ we have that $f(x, a=1) = 0$ always.

For $b = 0.5$,  a solution can be analytically given: in this case  we have

$$
f(x, b = 0.5) =  (\frac{1+a}{2})^x -  a^{x/2}
$$
Since by AM-GM-inequality, $\frac{1+a}{2} \ge a^{1/2}$, this gives
$
f(x, b = 0.5) \ge  0
$
with equality only for $a=1$ (by AM-GM) for arbitrary $x$.

Moving away from $b=0.5$, a solution for each $a$ exists for a specific $x$. E.g. for $b= 0.4$ we have
$$
f(x, b= 0.4) = 2 (1+a)^x - 2^x (a^{0.4x} + a^{0.6 x}) = 0
$$
and solutions are for example (using Matlabs fzero)

$(a,x) = (0.45, 317.8779) ; (0.5, 66.4909) ; (0.55, 43.6458) ; (0.6, 35.4395) ; (0.65, 31.3039) ; (0.75,  27.3412) ; (0.85,  25.6856) ; (0.95,  25.0660); (0.99,  25.0025) $

For very large $x$, there can be no solution any more when $(1+a)^x = 2^x  a^{0.4 x}$ or $1+a_0 = 2 a_0^{0.4} $ which gives $a_0≈0.43948$.

Generally, we have solutions $f(x) = 0 $ for $a > a_0$ where $a_0$ is given by $1+a_0 = 2  a_0^{b}$. When inverting, this gives the above conjecture.